# Is there a way to define a union type of two types if one extends the other?

Tags: typescript

```
interface Person {
    firstName: string;
}
interface PersonWithAge extends Person {
    age: number
}
type AnyPerson = Person | PersonWithAge;

let user: AnyPerson = {
    firstName: "Malcolm"
};

user.age = 25;
```

I get the following error:

"Property 'age' does not exist on type 'Person'."

Why is this not allowed? What is the correct way of achieving this?

Comment: I do not understand your question. You have a correct union of a type and another one which extends the first. The error is also correct. As `AnyPerson` could be either a `Person` *without* the `age` property or a `PersonWithAge` just assuming that is present is wrong...

Comment: Post code not pictures please

Comment: Ah - it's because I'm setting the age field after the type has been inferred.

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use `interface AnyPerson extends Person { age?: number; }` instead?  It kind of looks like you expect `age` to act like an optional property.

Answer (score 2):

You can access only members common to all constituents of a union. In this case `age` is only in `PersonWithAge` so `user.age` is not a valid access (since if `user` is `Person` is does not have `age`).

You ca use an `in` type guard to narrow the union to `PersonWithAge`:

```
interface Person {
  name: string
}

interface PersonWithAge extends Person {
  age: number;
}

type AnyPerson = Person | PersonWithAge;

declare var user: AnyPerson;
if('age' in user ) {
  user.age // user is PersonWithAge so this is ok now
}
```

[play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4CwAUMsiHALYQBcyGYUoA5sQL7HGiSyIrpTYQAdWBgAFgEEmKCAA9IIACYY0mHPmKk402iACuFAEbQA3Gw5EwATwAOKCSCv9ByALyqB6gD4fBI8VIQZkTEihAIADZwUCgAbtHIehjQtA5OaiDBwDAAFADk2hB5yKCJyVDIAJQaJGXQAHSFyAD0zXUVwCrOOP6S0nRYyOKdJSpYANZkWADubEA)